# Detecting if state of any widget in a form has changed

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a form with a QStackedWidget. The QStackedWidget has multiple widgets inside it. For instance QLineEdit , QCheckBox , QLineEdit. Now I have a "Save" button which should be only enabled if the state of any widget changes otherwise it remains disabled. I know I could go to each individual widget and make the appropriate changes that would enable/disable the save button. I wanted to know what would be the fastest and the simplest way to accomplish this task ?

Comment: What do you mean by "state of widget changes" ?

Comment: By changes i mean for QLineEdit if text is typed into it. For QSlider if its value is changed or moved back and forth. For QCheckBox if its value is toggled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect the signals of your widgets which are related to some state change to a slot to enable the save button :

```
connect(ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(enableSaveButton()));
connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),this,SLOT(enableSaveButton()));
connect(ui->checkBox,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(enableSaveButton()));

void MyWidget::enableSaveButton()
{
    ui->saveButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom widget. Extend all inputs using that custom widget.

Now you can use signal or savestate variable.

Whenever there is change emit signal. Pass this signal to save button state slot.

In starting it may look lengthy but later it will speed up your work. Also try to promoting classes if you are have UI based design. So custom widget won't be problem in any case.